# matching data by row name and column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match

We can create two data.frames in R by this:

```
Y1 <- c(14,12,11,12)
Y2 <- c(13,10,15,16)

df1 <- data.frame(Y1,Y2)
rownames(df1) <- c('boy','girl','man','woman')


A <- 1:5
type_y <- c(1,1,2,1,2)
SEX <- c('boy','girl','boy','man','woman')
df2 <- data.frame(A,type_y,SEX)
```

I want to create a new variable in `df2`, say `x`, that matches

- `SEX` with the rowname in `df1` &
- `Type_y` value with the corresponding `Y1 | Y2` value

**So our `df2$x` == 14,12,13,11,16**

Comment: Have you used `match`

Comment: along these lines, `df2$X <- df1[match(df2$SEX,rownames(df1) & df2$type_y, ...]`

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the output earlier

Comment: I think you can use `ifelse` or row/column indexing

Comment: Shouldn't the last element be 16 instead of 12?

Comment: I think df2$x should be 14,12,13,11,16

Comment: what i tihnk you are suggesting would be very tedious, as i must write a `ifelse` for each poossible outcome.

Comment: Have you checked the solution below?

Comment: correct, apologies, will update, just trying to form a reprodible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a numeric index by `match`ing the 'SEX' of 'df2' and row names of 'df1' ('i1').  We get the corresponding elements of 'Y1' and 'Y2' based on 'i1', `cbind` ('m1'), extract the elements of 'm1' based on the row (`1:nrow(df2)`), column (`df2$type_y`) index.

```
 i1 <- match(df2$SEX, row.names(df1))
 m1 <- cbind(df1$Y1[i1], df1$Y2[i1])
 df2$x <- m1[cbind(1:nrow(df2), df2$type_y)]
 df2$x
 #[1] 14 12 13 11 16
```

Comment: @user08041991  Just updated with some description.  Please check.